# extract files from a .exe file using the windows command line

Tags: powershell, cmd

Can anybody suggest me how to extract files from a .exe file using the windows command line. And I want to execute this command in power shell. I tried some possibilities but I am unsuccessful. I know how to do it for msi files but I need for .exe files. Please help me

This is one of my example

```
$command = @'
extract /c "D:\depot\main-copy\Setup.exe" "D:\depot\main-copy\staging"
'@
Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not opposed to using 3rd party utilities you could go with 7zip that has a handy portable [command line tool](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) you could use. This, of course, assumes that the exe in question can be unpacked in the first place.

Comment: It depends on how it was packed into the exe file.

Comment: What kind of EXE is it? Self-extracting ZIP? Self-extracting 7z? Packed with one of numerous EXE packers? Embedded resources? Renamed archive file? Please edit that into your question.